# python multiplication goes to tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm writing code with some easy maths but I ran into the problem that everytime I multiply a variable and an int it becomes a tuple. I don't even know what that is!

Here is the code with the variable:

```
e=0                                                
j=0
```

And here the code with the actual multiplication:

```
p1 = e * 3,5
p1 = p1 + j * 2,5
if w == 1:
    p1 = p1 * 0,8
print (p1)
return p1
```

So, I'd like to know how that creates a tuple and what a tuple even is.

Comment: The decimal separator in Python is always `.`, not `,`.

Comment: *"how that creates a tuple"* - you put a comma in it. Floating point literals must use `.`. If you want to know what a tuple is, read the docs.

Comment: Also `2.5` is not an `int`eger which means "whole number", but a `float`ing point number that represents binary fractions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your locale aware separator here.

Floats require a `.` not `,`. The comma defines a tuple according to the Python grammar.

So:

```
p1 = e * 3,5
```

is parsed as:

```
p1 = ((e * 3), 5) # a tuple!
```

You should instead do:

```
p1 = e * 3.5
```

Comment: oh yes. it's right. I used the comma because we do it with a comma in Germany... so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're storing a tuple in the variables. When you do:

```
    pi = e * 5,3
```

You're multiplying e with 5 and storing the product along with 3 as a tuple in the variable pi.

A tuple is an immutable sequence of Python objects. Tuples are sequences, just like lists. The differences between tuples and lists are, the tuples cannot be changed unlike lists and tuples use parentheses, whereas lists use square brackets.

Comment: *"A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects."* - no, you can put mutable objects in tuples.

Comment: Tuples themselves are immutable. They can contain references to mutable objects.

Comment: Correct, but that's not what you've written. *"sequence of immutable Python objects"* -> *"immutable sequence of Python objects"*

Comment: Updated the language.